# How to Navigate with Passing Arguments in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, navcontroller

Could someone provide a clear explanation or example code demonstrating how to navigate between destinations and pass arguments using Jetpack Compose?

In LoginPage1 when I click on button I want to go to next page with same param

```
//MainActivity.kt
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
) {
    LoginPage1(navController)
}

//LoginPage1
Button(
    onClick = { "go to next page" },
    shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(orange),
) {
}
```

I tried this but I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`:

```
Button(
    onClick = { navController.navigate("onboardingPage1") },
    shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(orange),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jetpack Compose, we can use the **NavController** to navigate between composable functions. We can also pass arguments between destinations.
First, you need to set up your navigation in your **MainActivity.kt**:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()

NavHost(navController, startDestination = "loginPage1") {
    composable("loginPage1") { LoginPage1(navController) }
    composable("onboardingPage1/{param}", arguments = listOf(navArgument("param") { type = NavType.StringType })) { backStackEntry ->
        OnboardingPage1(backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("param"))
    }
}
```

***{param}*** is a placeholder here for the argument that you want to pass to **onboardingpage1**.

Then, in **LoginPage1**, you can navigate to **onboardingpage1** and pass an argument like:

```
Button(
    onClick = { navController.navigate("onboardingpage1/actual_value") },
    shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(orange),
) {
    Text("Go to next page")
}
```

Here also replace ***"onboardingpage1/actual_value"*** with your actual route and parameter.

In **onboardingpage1**, you can retrieve the passed argument like:

```
@Composable
fun onboardingpage1(param: String?) {
    // Use param here
}
```

The **NullPointerException** you’re seeing might be due to **navController** being null at the time of the **onClick** event. Make sure **navController** is properly initialized before it’s used.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to declare param in destination route

```
object Constants {
    const val USER_DETAIL = "USER_DETAIL/{USER_ID}"
}
```

On Navigation Button Click

```
rootNavController.navigate(Constants.USER_DETAIL.replace("USER_ID",userId))
```

get param value in below way in Nav graph

```
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Login.route
    ){
        // .... 
        
        //.....
        composable(Constants.UserDetail) {
            val userId = it.arguments?.getString("USER_ID")?.toLong() ?: -1L
            UserDetailScreen(
                userId = userId
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing details about it.

Comment: JKSOL Infotech Right? @NiraliPandya

Comment: Yes, I was a former employee of it.